# Can you sort n integers in O(n) amortized complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Is it theoretically possible to sort an array of n integers in an amortized complexity of O(n)?

What about trying to create a worst case of O(n) complexity?

Most of the algorithms today are built on O(nlogn) average + O(n^2) worst case.
Some, while using more memory are O(nlogn) worst.

Can you with no limitation on memory usage create such an algorithm?
What if your memory is limited? how will this hurt your algorithm?

Comment: A vote down without a comment?

Comment: I don't see a downvote right now (perhaps undone?)  However, a couple of obvious reasons why someone might downvote it:  it sounds similar to homework; it might be better suited to cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any page on the intertubes that deals with comparison-based sorts [will tell you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list) that you **cannot** sort faster than `O(n lg n)` with comparison sorts. That is, if your sorting algorithm decides the order by comparing 2 elements against each other, you cannot do better than that. Examples include quicksort, bubblesort, mergesort.

Some algorithms, like count sort or bucket sort or radix sort do not use comparisons. Instead, they rely on the properties of the data itself, like the range of values in the data or the size of the data value.

Those algorithms **might** have faster complexities. Here is an example scenario:

> You are sorting `10^6` integers, and each integer is between `0` and `10`. Then you can just count the number of zeros, ones, twos, etc. and spit them back out in sorted order. That is how countsort works, in `O(n + m)` where `m` is the number of values your datum can take (in this case, `m=11`).

Another:

> You are sorting `10^6` binary strings that are all at most `5` characters in length. You can use the radix sort for that: first split them into 2 buckets depending on their first character, then radix-sort them for the second character, third, fourth and fifth. As long as each step is a stable sort, you should end up with a perfectly sorted list in `O(nm)`, where m is the number of digits or bits in your datum (in this case, `m=5`).

But in the general case, you cannot sort faster than `O(n lg n)` reliably (using a comparison sort).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite happy with the accepted answer so far. So I'm retrying an answer:

> Is it theoretically possible to sort an array of n integers in an amortized complexity of O(n)?

The answer to this question depends on the machine that would execute the sorting algorithm. If you have a random access machine, which can operate on exactly 1 bit, you can do [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) for integers with at most `k` bits, which was already suggested. So you end up with complexity `O(kn)`.
But if you are operating on a fixed size word machine with a word size of at least `k` bits (which all consumer computers are), the best you can achieve is `O(n log n)`. This is because either `log n < k` or you could do a [count sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_sort) first and then sort with a `O (n log n)` algorithm, which would yield the first case also.

> What about trying to create a worst case of O(n) complexity?

That is not possible. A link was already given. The idea of the proof is that in order to be able to sort, you have to decide for every element to be sorted if it is larger or smaller to any other element to be sorted. By using transitivity this can be represented as a decision tree, which has `n` nodes and `log n` depth at best. So if you want to have performance better than `Ω(n log n)` this means removing edges from that decision tree. But if the decision tree is not complete, than how can you make sure that you have made a correct decision about some elements `a` and `b`?

> Can you with no limitation on memory usage create such an algorithm?

So as from above that is not possible. And the remaining questions are therefore of no relevance.

Answer (score 2):

If the integers are in a limited range then an O(n) "sort" of them would involve having a bit vector of "n" bits ... looping over the integers in question and setting the n%8 bit of offset n//8 in that byte array to true.  That is an "O(n)" operation.  Another loop over that bit array to list/enumerate/return/print all the set bits is, likewise, an O(n) operation.  (Naturally O(2n) is reduced to O(n)).

This is a special case where n is small enough to fit within memory or in a file (with seek()) operations).  It is not a general solution; but it is described in Bentley's "Programming Pearls" --- and was allegedly a practical solution to a real-world problem (involving something like a "freelist" of telephone numbers ... something like: find the first available phone number that could be issued to a new subscriber).

(Note: log(10**10) is ~24 bits to represent every possible integer up to 10 digits in length ... so there's plenty of room in 2**31 bits of a typical Unix/Linux maximum sized memory mapping).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: "Radix sort's efficiency is O(kn) for n keys which have k or fewer digits", that is closer to what I want but that is not it. I am aware of that sort but, it has a limitation. Can you do it without this limitation? Or provide an explanation why not?

Comment: No, a general sort fast than O(n log n) is not possible. If you can't rely on special properties of the data (like radix sort) you need a comparison function, and the explanation why a comparison sort needs at least O(n log n) is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list

Comment: @Vadiklk In your question you state "Can you with no limitation on memory usage create such an algorithm?" Why did you say this if in fact you do want to impose limitations?

Comment: I wrote that I would find an algorithm that has no limitations on memory usage (uses infinity memory) but sorts it in o(n). Radix sort limits the numbers I want to sort without any justification.

Comment: @Vadiklk the justification is to achieve O(n)!